# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^5}$ using $u$ substitution and the log identity for integrating $x^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.3

Integrate $$\int \frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^5}$$ using $u$ substitution.

Can somebody verify the following solution for me? Thanks!!

---

Let $u = \ln(x)$. Then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$ and thus $x \, du=dx$. Thus we have:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^5} &= \int \frac{1}{xu^5} \, x \, du = \int \frac{du}{u^5} = \int u^{-5} du \\
&= \frac{u^{-4}}{-4} + C \\
&= - \frac{1}{4 \ (\ln(x))^4} + C.
\end{align}

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old saying is never say never, but I'll be bold and say never, ever mix the variables in a substitution. You should write
$$ \int \frac{dx}{x( \ln x)^5}\, dx = \int \frac{1}{(\ln x)^5} \, \frac{dx}{x} = 
\int \frac 1{u^5} \, du$$ which is exactly what you obtained except for that [terrible horrible no good very bad first step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_and_the_Terrible,_Horrible,_No_Good,_Very_Bad_Day).

Comment: Can you explain why you have such strong convictions on this matter?